# ClassNotFoundException for custom ImageView in Android app

Tags: android

I am getting following exception...

```
08-12 14:19:41.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(797): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.widgets.utils.CustomRoundedCornerImageView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[.]
```

I have created a custom ImageView i.e. **com.widgets.utils.CustomRoundedCornerImageView** and using it in a layout xml . The CustomRoundedCornerImageView.java is in class path with other classes.

**CustomRoundedCornerImageView.java**

```
package com.widgets.utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CustomRoundedCornerImageView extends ImageView {

    public CustomRoundedCornerImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public CustomRoundedCornerImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomRoundedCornerImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

            Bitmap b =  ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap() ;
            Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

            Bitmap roundBitmap = getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap,30);
            canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0,0 , null);
    }

    public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
        Bitmap roundedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
                .getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(roundedBitmap);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = pixels;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
            paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return roundedBitmap;
    }

}
```

**layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/picture_frame"
        android:layout_width="70px"
        android:layout_height="70px"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40px"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="@drawable/picture_frame">
    <com.widgets.utils.CustomRoundedCornerImageView 
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:focusable="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can you help me why I am getting ClassNotFoundException ?

Comment: have u defined the class in the manifest

Comment: @Raghu Its a class not Activity

Comment: @Raghu yes, if it is an Activity then I could have defined it in AndroidManifest.xml , It is a simple ImageVIew .

Comment: I built a project using your ImageView and it worked fine. Perhaps you should clean your project and refresh your directories.

Comment: @CaspNZ Thanks for trying this, however I have already done the same couple of times, Only difference is, I am trying to add this new custom class in an existing Project which is already in my device. Any other idea?

Comment: Can you give us some more of the error in logcat

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
<com.widgets.utils.CustomRoundedCornerImageView 
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:focusable="false" />
```

in this you have to change

```
<ImageView class="com.widgets.utils.CustomRoundedCornerImageView" 
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:focusable="false" />
```

Comment: is there reason as to why this must be done? It causes further problems down the line, and is contradictory to all of the Android tutorial information

Comment: According to docs, you need to explicitly use the `class` attribute if the extended one is an inner class, otherwise it can be used as an xml attribute directly.

Comment: I have got warning 'Unknown attribute class' ; any idea how to remove it? (indeed, your solution doesn't seem to work for me, probably linked to this warning) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If None of the existing solutions are working, then it is a `problem with multidex file`.

One of the **main disadvantages** of using multidex is -
When we have `multiple dex files` and suppose We have a `CustomClass` that is contained in ***dex-1 file*** and `Activity` where we are using that class is contained in another dex file lets say ***dex-2***. Then it will generate a runtime error: *ClassNotFoundException*.

This is because both files are not placed in same dex file and we have little control over which classes will be placed in which dex file.

**Probable Solutions:**

Remove unused functions or libraries - it will reduce number of functions in your project that can lead to fewer dex files.