# Referencing ImageView subclass getting ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, subclass, android-imageview, classcastexception

I have a project where I am trying to make a subclass to ImageView, to add some methods I want to use. I'm only a couple of weeks into Android coding so I'm not very experienced, and fairly new to OOP. As I couldn't get it to work in my main project I made a small test project, alas, I get the same error.

First I created a new class ImageViewCustom.java that extends ImageView

```
public class ImageViewCustom extends ImageView {}
```

(I have added the constructors from the super class)

In the XML I did like so after reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7039470)

```
<ImageView class="com.example.testcustomclass.ImageViewCustom" 
    android:id="@+id/imageViewCustom" ... />
```

This works to build and run, but then when I try to reference it in MainActivity like so

```
ImageViewCustom imageViewTest = (ImageViewCustom)
    findViewById(R.id.imageViewCustom);
```

I get...

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
    ComponentInfo{com.example.testcustomclass.MainActivity}:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView 
    cannot be cast to com.example.testcustomclass.ImageViewCustom
```

What am I doing wrong? D: I assume I am missing something very basic as this is an almost empty project. FYI I'm trying to get an assignment done by tonight (eh!) and got so much duplicate code I wanted to do a subclass, but I am stumped and stressed out >_< lack of sleep etc.

(edit, fixing code formatting...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your XML is off...  I always use

```
<com.my.project.MyView
     android:id="..."
/>
```

which I believe is the proper way to do so.

Comment: That works, apparently I did the problem solving the wrong way in that link I provided, haha. Talk about confusion, thanks! xD

Answer (score 0):

If your referencing your view in a xml layout you don't need to use class

replace

```
<ImageView class="com.example.testcustomclass.ImageViewCustom" 
    android:id="@+id/imageViewCustom" ... />
```

with

```
<com.example.testcustomclass.ImageViewCustom
    android:id="@+id/imageViewCustom" ... />
```